# MVC Razor view displays the wrong time value of a DateTime object

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an `Order` object, that contains two `DateTime` attributes called `LendDate` and `ReturnDate` as seen below:

```
public class Order
{
    public DateTime LendDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm displaying a list of these objects in a basic index, auto-generated by ASP.Net, like so:

```
foreach (var item in Model.orderList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReturnDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(ResGlobal.Details, "Details", new { id = item.OrderID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

I have a display template (`Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\DateTime.cshtml`) that should ensure the right format for the datetime objects (I have tested this, by changing the format around and it works fine). It looks like this:

`@String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt}", Model.Date)`

The problem here is that it shows the object's date time as the correct date but the time is always set at 12:00.

I have checked the database and debugged the code and the correct dates AND times are passed to the view successfully, so **why does it insist on setting the time at 12:00?**

If I change the format around, I sometimes get the time as 00:00 instead of 12:00, which doesn't help.

I can make it display the correct date and time if I do:

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate.Day)-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate.Month)-@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate.Year) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate.Hour):@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LendDate.Minute)
</td>
```

Which I do not believe is a good solution, not to mention ugly. This also shows the correct time, so the problem is not that the correct time is lost when passing the orders.

**I want the view to display dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of your display template: you are passing only date part to the `string.Format` function.
Try to just pass a model(your date time object) like this:

```
@String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt}", Model)
```

Also IMHO it's cleaner to just call `.ToString(string format)` method on the date object:

```
@Model.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

Another way to format dates is to create a view-model class and use`[DisplayFormat]` attribute to specify date time format(it should work for `EditorFor` as well).